# Quick Inverse Derivative Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So I was given a problem that I was able to work my way through, but I'm not entirely sure if my process was correct. I started with the following table and prompt:
[image]

[image]

So after applying the inverse derivative rule, which is as follows, $(f^-1)(a)=$ $\frac {1}{f'(f^-1(a))}$. The application of this rule along with the derivative step in this process led me to this answer:
[image]
This is where I'm struggling a bit, is this answer right? I'm second guessing myself and thinking that the same answer without the $4$ and the $2$ in the last expression might be correct but I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$g(x)=f(4x)-f(2x)$$

Hence, by chain rule, we have

$$g'(x)=f'(4x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(4x)-f'(2x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(2x)=4f'(4x)-2f'(2x)$$

That's why you get those coefficients.